# React-Redux: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(UploadInternal)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Duplicated Code Sandbox**
https://ndg6d.csb.app/

**Full Error**
`Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(UploadInternal)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(UploadInternal) in connect opt`.

**Situation**
Everything was working correctly, then updated react 15.x to 16.13.x, and react-redux from 5.x to 7.2.x, and now the error above occurs on a component several levels deep.

I've checked the [ReactRedux Docs](https://react-redux.js.org/troubleshooting#:%7E:text=Could%20not%20find%20%22store%22%20in,of%20React%20and%20React%20Redux.) and verified I've followed their recommended steps. And I've read all the other similar cases listed here on StackOverflow, but have not resolved the issue. Specifically, a store is passed to a provider that wraps the root app `<Provider store={store}><App/></Provider>`, and the intermediary components are connected with `connect` via ReactRedux, so I'm not sure why one of the nested children doesn't have access to the store.

*index.js*

```
   const store = configureStore(preloadedState);

    ReactDOM.render((
        <Provider store={store}>
          <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
              <Route component={App} />
            </ConnectedRouter>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </Provider>
      ), document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

*configureStore.js*

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../components/app/reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import history from '../history/history'

export default function configureStore(initialState) {

  var middleware;
  var storeEnhancer;
  var store;

  if(initialState){
    middleware = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)];

    storeEnhancer = compose(
      applyMiddleware(...middleware)
    );

    store =   createStore(
      combineReducers({
        root: rootReducer,
        router: connectRouter(history) 
      }),
      initialState,
      applyMiddleware(...middleware)););
  }else{
    middleware = [thunk];
    storeEnhancer = compose(
      applyMiddleware(...middleware)
    );

    store = createStore(
      combineReducers({
        root: rootReducer,
        router: connectRouter(history) 
      }),
      applyMiddleware(...middleware)););
  }


    if (module.hot) {
        // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
        module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
            const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers');
            store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
        });
    }

    return store;
}
```

*Child.jsx & NestedChild.jsx (Inside Child.jsx)* -- Just the bottom of the files to show the Components are connected:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {

  const {root, ...rest} = state;
  const reduxState = {...root};

  return {
    reduxState
  };
};


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=>{
  return {dispatch};
};

const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) => {
  return Object.assign({}, ownProps, stateProps, dispatchProps);
};

const options = {

};


Child_or_NestedChild = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps, options)(Child_or_NestedChild);

export default muiThemeable()(Child_or_NestedChild);
```

Comment: can you provide us a codesanbox to replicate the issue?

Comment: Does if help if you re install node modules? Remove `node_modules` and lock files (yarn.lock package.lock) and re run `npm install` or `yarn`.

Comment: @HMR I did remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and re-install, but it didn't work. @tmhao2005 Here's a simplified code sandbox with the issue: https://ndg6d.csb.app/. I'll add it to the main post, too.

Comment: @JustCodin Thank you for the sandbox but that doesn't demonstrate the problem described in your question. If I were to replace App in [index.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/ndg6d?file=/src/index.js) with a component defined in index that uses useSelector there is no problem getting state from redux store.

Comment: @HMR Perhaps we're miscommunicating. But if you click the button in the sandbox, it generates the error that the nested child component doesn't have access to the store in the context. I did a little more digging and see the `<Dialog/>` (from Material UI 0.22) that wraps `<UploadInternal/>` is the culprit. If `<Dialog/>` is removed, `<UploadInternal/>` receives the store. But I need the `<Dialog/>` so I'm trying to understand why this happens and to correct it.

Comment: I've got the same issue as you, using MUI v0.20.2. Thanks for the heads up about `<Dialog />`. I'm running MUI v4 concurrently as I'm migrating the app over, guess now might be a good time to switch over.

Comment: @GregK I submit this answer, but @Jean-François Fabre deleted it. -- I believe this is caused by an outdated `MaterialUI` component that's creating a popover outside the context as mentioned [here](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/241#issuecomment-604314058). The child nested in the `MaterialUI` component `Dialog` throws the error. However, if the child is not nested in `Dialog`, then it has access to the store. This shows that the root, its children, and grandchildren have access to the store, and shows `Dialog` causes the breaking boundary in this situation.

Comment: I am running into similar issue with mdbreact modal component.. were you able to fix this ?

Comment: @Sujith Yes, I posted the answer, but it was deleted by a moderator. 

I believe this is caused by an outdated `MaterialUI` component that's creating a popover outside the context as mentioned [here](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/241#issuecomment-604314058). The child nested in the `MaterialUI` component `Dialog` throws the error. However, if the child is not nested in `Dialog`, then it has access to the store. This shows that the root, its children, and grandchildren have access to the store, and shows `Dialog` causes the breaking boundary in this situation.