# React-Redux & Material UI: Component doesn't pass store to 'connected' child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

**Duplicated Code Sandbox** https://ndg6d.csb.app/

**Full Error** `Uncaught Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(UploadInternal)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(UploadInternal) in connect opt.`

**Situation** Everything was working correctly, then updated react 15.x to 16.13.x, and react-redux from 5.x to 7.2.x, and now the error above occurs when a connected component is passed as a child to the `Dialog` component in `Upload.jsx`. The store is passed correctly to the child component if it's not nested in `Dialog`. I am using a very old version of Material UI (v0.20.2), but it's `package.json` file lists both dependencies `react` and `react-dom` as `^16.0.0`, so it should be ok.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63406075/react-redux-could-not-find-store-in-the-context-of-connectuploadinternal?noredirect=1#comment112245889_63406075

Comment: Your material UI has been deprecated: https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui

Comment: @HMR I made this post as I believe it's more clear. Should I delete the other one? And although Material UI v0.20.2 is deprecated, it should still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is caused by an outdated `MaterialUI` component that's creating a popover outside the context as mentioned [here](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/241#issuecomment-604314058). The child nested in the `MaterialUI` component `Dialog` throws the error. However, if the child is not nested in `Dialog`, then it has access to the store. This shows that the root, its children, and grandchildren have access to the store, and shows `Dialog` causes the breaking boundary in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the index.js if you haven't done that:

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducers";

const composeEnhances = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : f => f;

const store = createStore(rootReducer,compose(applyMiddleware(thunk),composeEnhances));

const app = (
<Provider store={store}>
   <App />
</Provider>
);
```

the reducer index.js file would be like :

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from "../components/app/reducers";

export default combineReducers({
// your reducers here
root: rootReducer,
});
```

Comment: I have something similar. Is there something different in your recommendation that's not shown in the code sandbox?

Comment: I checked the code but I couldn't run it, have you tried to pass {...this.props} as an argument to the Dialog?

Comment: Passing {...props} had no effect. If you click the sandbox link it opens a live UI, and if you click the bottom right button 'open sandbox' you can see the code and make live changes, and there's a refresh button, too.